# Researching family history in Albania?

Tags: albania

We have been looking for records of Bektash Shkembi from Albania and have not been able to find any.

Does anyone have any suggestions where to begin researching family history in Albania so that we may be able to find him?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy StackExchange. As it stands this isn't a good fit for our format - do you have a specific question to ask, or more information you can provide about the ancestor you are researching and what searches you have already tried?

Comment: Some critical details to help find descendants of your ancestor will be to know where and when he lived.  Be aware that if he may still be alive then your question will be off-topic for our site which is not about "Locating identifiable living individuals" (http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: From your user card I have taken a guess that your ancestor may have been Albanian and edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: @PolyGeo The first version of this question included an odd assortment of tags, which, along with the original wording, led me to believe that target person Bektash Shkembi emigrated from Albania, but that the original poster did not know the destination.

Comment: @bgwiehle Yes it had tags of [tag:australia] and [tag:native-american] which I guessed were attempts at finding an [tag:Albania] tag.  I could easily be wrong but I wanted to focus the question in one clear direction, which can be easily altered at any time by its original asker using the edit button.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are not a lot of resources listed there yet, there is a [FamilySearch.org page devoted to Albania](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Albania) which may offer you some ideas.

For example, if you know the jurisdiction that he lived in (see list below from FamilySearch), then perhaps that can narrow the search for any government records that may be available:

> - Berat
> - Diber
> - Durres
> - Elbasan
> - Fier
> - Gjirokaster
> - Korce
> - Kukes
> - Lezhe
> - Shkoder
> - Tirane
> - Vlore